# Cypher - calculate the correspondence between 2 entities

Tags: python, sql, neo4j, cypher

I am new to Cypher, I have a bit of trouble with a query, so my query consists of calculating the number of matches between two entities, I managed to do it in SQL to be able to translate it into Cypher but I didn't can't do it ...
here is my SQL request :

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM Dogs 
INNER JOIN Cats ON condition
```

Comment: Take a look at : https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher/guide-sql-to-cypher/

Answer (score 0):

With a presumption about your graph, this might do it

```
(d:Dog)-[:condition]-(c:Cats) return count(*)
```

or, if you want to know the count by condition

```
(d:Dog)-[r:condition]-(c:Cats) return type(r) as condition, count(*) as ct
```